# time lag in program for centroid calculation

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to determine the centroid of one specific object using OpenCV and Python.
I am using the following code, but it is taking too much time to calculate the centroid.
I need a faster approach for this -- should I change the resolution of the cameras in order to increase the computing speed?
This is my code:

```
meanI=[0]
meanJ=[0]

#taking infinite frames continuously to make a video
while(True):
    ret, frame = capture.read()
    rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(frame , 0)
    content_red = rgb_image[:,:,2] #red channel of image
    content_green = rgb_image[:,:,1] #green channel of image
    content_blue = rgb_image[:,:,0] #blue channel of image
    r = rgb_image.shape[0] #gives the rows of the image matrix
    c = rgb_image.shape[1] # gives the columns of the image matrix
    d = rgb_image.shape[2] #gives the depth order of the image matrux
    binary_image = np.zeros((r,c),np.float32)
    for i in range (1,r):  #thresholding the object as per requirements
        for j in range (1,c):
            if((content_red[i][j]>186) and (content_red[i][j]<230) and \
               (content_green[i][j]>155) and (content_green[i][j]<165) and \
               (content_blue[i][j]> 175) and (content_blue[i][j]< 195)):
                binary_image[i][j] = 1
                meanI.append(i)
                meanJ.append(j)

    cv2.imshow('frame1',binary_image)
    cv2.waitKey()
    cox = np.mean(meanI) #x-coordinate of centroid
    coy = np.mean(meanJ) #y-coordinate of centroid
```

Comment: look at cv2.findContours() and cv2.moments() instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered, nested loops in Python are [very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3542968/1601291). It is best to avoid iterating over every pixel using nested loops. Fortunately, OpenCV has some built-in functions that do exactly what you are trying to achieve: [`inRange()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange), which creates a binary image of pixels which fall in between the specified bounds, and [`moments()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?#moments), which you can use to calculate the centroid of a binary image. I strongly suggest reading over OpenCV's [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/index.html) to get a feel for what the library offers.

Combining these two functions gives the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

lower = np.array([175, 155, 186], np.uint8) # Note these ranges are BGR ordered
upper = np.array([195, 165, 230], np.uint8)
binary = cv2.inRange(im, lower, upper) # im is your BGR image
moments = cv2.moments(binary, True)
cx = moments['m10'] / moments['m00']
cy = moments['m01'] / moments['m00']
```

`cx` and `cy` are the x- and y-coordinates of the image centroid. This version is a whopping **3000 times faster** than using nested loops.